# Getting bytes from user inputted integers

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

So I can manage to get the user inputted integer into $v0, then I use

```
la $t0 ($v0)
```

and I store the integer entered into $t0. How would I try to get the first byte of the interger from $t0. Every time I try to use

```
lb $t1 0($t0)
```

I get an error: Exception 7 [Bad data address] occurred and ignored.

Comment: I assume `la $t0 ($v0)` is a type and you meant `lw $t0, ($v0)`

Answer (score 0):

The `lb` instruction is used to read a byte *from memory*. That is, `lb $t1, 0($t0)` would attempt to read a byte from memory at the address stored in `$t0` (it would also sign-extend that byte, which may not be what you want).

What you want to do is not to read from memory, but isolate the least significant byte of a value already stored in a register. You can do that with the `andi` instruction:

```
andi $t1, $t0, 0xFF  # $t1 = $t0 AND 0xFF
```

You should read up on [bitwise logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation), since such operations are quite common in assembly language code.